# how to stop adblocks from blocking my revive adserver banner promotions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads, adblock

I am using revive adserver to show my users promotions banners and track conversion. The problem is that adblock completely blocks my banners. I would like to change my banner code so that my users who are using adblock still will be able to know about promotions.

Comment: Tell your customers how to create exceptions for your page, or name your banners so that they won't match the rules of the ads. Maybe some users have activated the AdBlocker because they don't want to se your promotions.

Comment: We are using add server only to track conversion. Earlier we had just hard-coded images and of course it wasn't blocked. I will try to go around that block leaving exception as a last thing to do.

Comment: Asking your users to create an exception might annoy them. If a user takes the time to install an adblock they probably are not going to click on ads anyway (they are either conserned about pricay or malware or just hate ads).

Comment: What will you do about this? https://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very complicated because new filters are being written and available every day. However, removing any code or markup and signifies that your ad is an ad can help.

Ie. Remove word like: ad, popup, banner, giveaway, etc.

Further, the best way is to determine what filter is blocking your ad, then alter the ad so that it isn't matched. Although if the site serving the ad has a lot of traffic a new filter will be written very quickly, and then at that point it's just a you against the world. So it's sort of pointless to even try.

An ad is an ad and will eventually be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rename the location of your adserver?  I noticed that AdBlock Plus also blocked my images because I used the word AdServer for the install and it was in my URL string.

Answer (score 0):

Revive Ad server is inherently blocked by ad blockers based on the URL structure. You can A change the domain and see if that works temporarily.
or B change the URL structure and domain, which would work and work longer, however, the Iframe and JS structure they use may be targeted.

Your other option is to load the ads yourself server side and make them look like content, but that will eventually get blocked.

And finally, you can go with ReviveAds ad block prevention. They are the only company that is able to deliver ads in real time across your ad space where your ads are blocked. They are 100% supported 24-7 so you have little downtime even if they do get blocked.

It is easier than constantly trying to battle on your own and the revenue is roughly the same.